# What components and valves do you need for this pneumatic system of 4 actuators powered by commands and distributed in 2 lines?

Tags: industrial-robot, first-robotics, logic-control, air-muscle

I was designing a pneumatic system, fed by a compressor (Tank = 6 liters, Pmax = 8 bar, Motor power = 1.5 HP, Flow = 180 l/min), and consisting of its FRL, some hoses for the ducts 4 mm standard polyurethane, and four cylinders (actuators).

Of which, two of the cylinders are arranged in serie on one of the branches of the pneumatic circuit and the other two also in series but in the other branch (but both branches fed from the same compressor).

And when I was needing is that by a command the two cylinders of one branch extend or retract at the same time, and that with another independent command the other two cylinders of the other branch contract or retract at the same time.

What type of components (valves and others...) would you need for a circuit of these characteristics, where the response speed of the actuators is an important factor?

It is important that the pneumatic pistons maintain their position until the opposite action is indicated.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: if the response speed is so important, then why do you not say what response speed you expect

Comment: @jsotola I haven't said it yet, but I would need the extension or retraction to be done in less than 1.5 seconds

Comment: this site is not a forum ... you do not release information in pieces ... all information should be in the question at the top of this page ... please add the requirement to the question

Comment: It depends on the type of valve that uses the speed of response. Assuming a speed of 25 cm/1.2 sec